# Trying to have a simple login using html and php

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to develop a program for a simple login using hard coded usernames and passwords. However, my html code shows the username and password box and it should redirect to the php file but it does not show anything on my php file output. this is my html code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form id='Login' action='homework2.php' method='POST' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
        <label for='username' >UserName:</label>
        <input type='text' name='username' id='username' maxlength="25" />
        <label for='password' >Password:</label>
        <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="25" />
        <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit'/>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my php file

```
<?php
function homework2() {
    if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $this->HandleError("UserName is empty!");
        return false;
    }
    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $this->HandleError("Password is empty!");
        return false;
    }
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    if (($username == 'elliez' && $password == 'tr789ial') ||($username == 'greatGuy' && $password == 'abc123') || ($username == 'blogger' && $password == '23seventeen23')) {
        echo "You have successfully logged in!";
        return true;
    }
    echo "Sorry, wrong information has been entered!";
    return false;
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm trying to echo out "you have successfully logged in!" however, it just shows a blank page after login.

Comment: you never call the `homework2` function

Comment: if you dont mind helping can you show me where to call the function

Comment: no need to have it, easier not to in this case, just remove it, you will then start getting some errors, like usng `$this`

Comment: Thank You so much!! You are really helpful!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the homework2() function

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['username']))
{
    die("UserName is empty!");
}
if (empty($_POST['password']))
{
    die("Password is empty!");
}
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);
if (($username == 'elliez' && $password == 'tr789ial') ||
    ($username == 'greatGuy' && $password == 'abc123') ||
    ($username == 'blogger' && $password == '23seventeen23'))
{
    echo "You have successfully logged in!";
} else {
    die("Sorry, wrong information has been entered!");
}
?>
```

Comment: why are you returning 'false' ?